# shifting origin in matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used the following code to plot in python, but the origin does not start from the left bottom corner. Instead, there is a margin.
Here is my plot:

[image: plot]

How can I shift the origin to left bottom corner?
I have used the following code:

```py
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
time= [0,1,2,3,4,5]
r1= [100,87,69,16,3,0]
r2= [200,163,127,61,14,0]
   
ax.plot(time, r1, '-o', label="1 μm")
ax.plot(time, r2, '-o', label="2 μm")

ax.legend()

plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.margins(x=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use set limits on x and y.

```
ax.set_xlim(0,max(time))
ax.set_ylim(0,max(r2))
```